# Understanding physical fitness anatomically

Tags: workout-routines, muscle, gym, books, medicine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are good books on muscle building heavily based on science?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6123/what-are-good-books-on-muscle-building-heavily-based-on-science)

Are there any books which explain the significance of each and every exercise we do in the gym? I do not mean one of those "guides to fitness" I'd rather like a book describing physical fitness from a human anatomy point of view. So that before we work out, we know exactly what is going to happen inside the body, inside the muscles and where and how much wear and tear happens when we do a workout and how to maintain a diet to compensate for that wear and tear? Basically a scientific/medical approach to physical fitness. The sort of workout an orthopedic/sports doctor would tell you to do rather than a fitness trainer.